# Bootstrap- Automatically adjust the font inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div in which I can write any text up to 20 characters. But the text is getting out of the div. [image]

I am setting it by decreasing `font-size`  property on character count but it is not applicable on all cases.
Is there any way to do it by applying any `twitter bootstrap` rule?

```
<div id="overlay_image_text"></div>
if(cs < 6)
    {
        if(this.engravingFontCaseSenstiveOptions(cText) == "Lower")
        {
         $('#overlay_image_text').css({'margin-top':'-170px'});
         $('#overlay_image_text').css({'font-size':68+'px'});
        }
        else if(this.engravingFontCaseSenstiveOptions(cText) == "Upper"){
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({'margin-top':'-154px'});
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({'font-size':48+'px'});
    }
else{
$('#overlay_image_text').css({'margin-top':'-170px'});
$('#overlay_image_text').css({'font-size':64+'px'});
}
}
else if(cs > 5 && cs <= 7)
{
if(this.engravingFontCaseSenstiveOptions(cText) == "Lower")
{
$('#overlay_image_text').css({'margin-top':'-152px'});
$('#overlay_image_text').css({'font-size':47+'px'});    
}
else if(this.engravingFontCaseSenstiveOptions(cText) == "Upper")
{
$('#overlay_image_text').css({'margin-top':'-140px'});
$('#overlay_image_text').css({'font-size':35+'px'});    
}
else
{
 $('#overlay_image_text').css({'margin-top':'-152px'});
 $('#overlay_image_text').css({'font-size':47+'px'});   
}
}
```

**CSS for parent element**

```
element.style {
    display: block;
    font-family: Cherokee;
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap does not have this function by default. BTW, are you trying to make the text's width the same as the div's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

Basically, I take advantage of the `scale()` in CSS and make the text fit in its parents. Please comment if you need further explanation ;)

```js
$(function(){
  $("#text").on("input", function(){
    var thisWidth = $(this).width();
    var parentWidth = $(this).parent().width();
    var scalingFactor = parentWidth/thisWidth;
    if (thisWidth > parentWidth) {
      $(this).css("transform", "scale("+scalingFactor+")");
    } else {
      $(this).css("transform", "scale(1)");
    }
  });
})
```

```css
#box {
  width:400px;
  background:#D8557F;
  border:10px solid #D8557F;
  height:100px;
}

#text {
  font-size:54px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float:left;
  transform-origin:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <div id="text" contenteditable="true">
    Edit me!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: exactly. That's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Would need to see the CSS code of the parent element containing it but try

```
#overlay_image_text {
      width:100%;
      font-size: auto;
}
```

Hope you get the idea. Also, apply padding/margin in **%** as needed.

Comment: Would need the code for the element that contains the div (possibly the element with the pink background) but did you try my code?